# Execute LINQ with or without where clause

Tags: c#, linq

In my example i want to get promotion elements for a promo code name that is provided if name is not provided then take all available promotions.

```
var result = from row in promoCodes.AsEnumerable() 
             where  (
                 !String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldTitle) && 
                 !String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterValue) && 
                 row[fieldTitle].Equals(filterValue)
             ) || true
             select new PromoCodeInfoContainer
             {
                 BannerLink = row["BannerLink"] as string
                 ....
             };
```

I tried to follow SQL technique where if no conditions provided then OR will be whatever that doesn't impact selection (|| true). In linq this didn't work, it always returns all entries regardless of "fieldTitle" and "filterValue" are not empty. Can anybody suggest a right way to do it?

Comment: well, the `|| true` looks like a good reason to return every row...

Comment: Yup @MarcGravell that is the problem

Comment: I'd say do two statements, one to check for promo elements, then a second for if none found. It'll be easier to read and simple.

Comment: Marc and @lazyberezovsky gave similar solution at pretty same time which I used and it works great. I used lazy's way it look more elegant but Marc was earlier. Correct me if I'm wrong. You are killing me guys. Marc - solution, Lazy - vote up. Thanks to both of you, appreciate such a quick response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, remove the `|| true` - that will return every row, always - hence the problem.

One nice way to do this would be composition - this then avoids the need to test the `fieldTitle` / `fieldValue` for every row when they have values, or do anything much at all per-row if they are blank:

```
var query = promoCodes.AsEnumerable();
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldTitle) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldValue))
{
    query = from row in query
            where filterValue.Equals(row[fieldTitle])
            select row;
}
var result = from row in query
             select new PromoCodeInfoContainer {...}
```

Note I also reversed the `Equals` so that the thing-we-know-isn't-null is on the left; although depending on the data-types, `Equals(x,y)` or `x == y` may be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = from row in promoCodes.AsEnumerable() 
             where  String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldTitle) ||                  
                    String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterValue) ||
                    row[fieldTitle].Equals(filterValue)  
             select new PromoCodeInfoContainer
             {
                 BannerLink = row["BannerLink"] as string
             };
```

If either `fieldTitle` of `filterValue` is null or empty, then row filtering will not be executed.

Another option (I think fluent interface looks better here):

```
var query = promoCodes.AsEnumerable();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldTitle) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(fieldValue))
    query = query.Where(row => row[fieldTitle].Equals(filterValue));

var result = query.Select(row => new PromoCodeInfoContainer { ... });
```